# how to give onblur and onkeypress in same line in yii and is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I create a form in that I want to use onblur and onkeypress in same line.

Is it possible?

```
<?php
    echo $form->textField($model, 'amount', array('name'=>'amount','onblur'=>'return checkallfield()', 'id'=>'amnt'));
?>
```

Where to give onkeypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it like you added `onblur`, as:

```
$form->textField($model,
    'amount',
    array(
        'name'=>'amount',
        'onblur'=>'return checkallfield();',
        'onkeypress'=>'return doKeyPress();',
        'id'=>'amnt'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use key press event in the same manner as blur:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'amount',array('name'=>'amount','onblur'=>'console.log("onblur event triggered")','onkeyup'=>'console.log("onkeyup event triggered")','id'=>'amnt')); ?>
```

Check console you will be able to see events.